# make media player

Tags: c#, media-player, mci

how can i add  "using MCI;" in my c# project to make media player ??????

Comment: You need to add a reference to "MCI" (whatever it is) to your Visual Studio project.... ?!?!  and then you need to type in "using MCI;" into your code...... not really clear what you're asking and where you're having trouble...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx

Comment: Aside - MCI is (I think) the Media Control Interface in windows...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import `winmm.dll`, it's found in "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
The code in c# looks like this:

`[DllImport("winmm.dll")]`

After that you need to define option to send comands to mci. Use the following code:

`private static extern long mciSendString(string command,StringBuilder returnValue,int returnLength,IntPtr winHandle);`

After this you can start using previously defined command. It should look something like this:

`mciSendString("open \"" + fileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias media", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);`

If you need any more help just ask (Sorry about bad english)

Comment: I have tried this code got from http://www.caveofprogramming.com/uncategorized/c-for-beginners-make-your-own-mp3-player-free/#comment-6018. But not worked for me.. No build errors!! But the mp3 file is not running.. I couldn’t hear the sound.. (The same mp3 file is working fine with window media player).. What to do?